# Как убрать в строке слово? PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dict, split, обработка-данных

Получаю данные в таком формате:

```
1st January 1919 - J. D. Salinger's birthday, author of Catcher in the Rye 
3rd January 1892 - J. R. R. Tolkien's birthday, author of The Hobbit & The Lord of the Rings 
4th January 1965 - T. S. Eliot's death, author of The Wast Land
```

Преобразую их в словари типа:

```
{'name': " J. D. Salinger's birthday", 'date': '1st/January/1919'} 
{'name': " J. R. R. Tolkien's birthday", 'date': '3rd/January/1892'} 
{'name': " T. S. Eliot's death", 'date': '4th/January/1965'}
```

Как убрать слова birthday и death?
Пыталась сделать str.split(' ')[0] , но тогда в принципе обрезает все.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо обрезать последнее слово, то так:

```
print(' '.join(" J. D. Salinger's birthday".split(' ')[:-1]))
```

Вывод:

```
 J. D. Salinger's
```

Т.е. делим строку по пробелам, берём срезом всё, кроме последнего элемента, получившийся список обратно склеиваем через пробелы.